# How to Publish a message with custom attributes with Dataflow

Tags: java, publish-subscribe, custom-attributes, dataflow

Gurus.

I tried to search on google and all, but I seem could not able to find any resource to publish a message with a custom attribute to a Pub/Sub Topic.

OBJECTIVE:

- One Topic with 2 Subscriptions
- Each Subscription has an Subscription filter for specific values:

  - SubscriptionA - attribute.table = "Table1"
  - SubscriptionB - attribute.table = "Table2"

ALREADY DONE:

- There would be specific Dataflow triggers watching each Subscription
- Filters already applied to each Subscription, where messages are routed to the specific Subscription.

CHALLENGE:

- How to write a simple message with a custom attribute to the Pub/Sub Topic like example:

  - APPLICATION_A - after previous execution, send a Pub/Sub Message with the value "Table1" for the attribute "table"
  - APPLICATION_B - after previous execution, send a Pub/Sub Message with the value "Table2" for the attribute "table"

NEXT STEPS:

- Maybe if anyone could point me to the right direction to achieve this? Or some sort of guide?
- Since most resource found are focused on just sending a message, but what about the attributes itself? Is there a possibility to add custom attributes when writing to Pub/Sub Topic through Dataflow/Beam?